# Using Find and Offset to check records in two tabs

Tags: vba, excel, find, offset

I'm trying to check two sets of information in two different tabs, and then get all the records into a third tab, highlighting discrepancies in the information and also records that are present in a set but not the other. As an added difficulty, the information that I need to check is not written exactly in the same way in both tabs. Eg: in one of the tabs products are called "Product 1, Product 2", etc, whereas the other uses just the numbers.

I'm pretty new to VBA, and my best idea so far is selecting a column with IDs in one of the sets and using Find to check the other set for matches. After that I'd like to use Offset on the value Find returns to check the other cells in the row.

However, I'm encountering and 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Below is the code, I'd really appreciate any help with using Offset in this scenario (or ideas on a more efficient way to get the results).

```
Sub Test()

Dim Candi_ID As String
Dim Full_Name As String
Dim i_Row As Object
Dim i_Cell As Range
Dim MD_Range As Integer
Dim i_Cell As Range

 Sheets("M Report").Select
 MD_Range = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) 'column with the IDs

For R = 2 To MD_Range
    Candi_ID = Sheets("M Report").Cells(R, 3)
    Full_Name = Sheets("M Report").Cells(R, 1)
    If Candi_ID <> "" Then
        With Sheets("i Report").Range("B:B")
        Set i_Cell = .Find(What:="*" & Candi_ID, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If i_Cell Is Nothing Then
                Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & Last_Row + 1) = Candi_ID
                Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & Last_Row + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                Last_Row = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & Last_Row + 1) = Candi_ID
            End If

            If Full_Name <> "" Then

                If Full_Name = i_Cell.Offset(0, -1) Then 'full name is one cell to the left of the ID cell
                    Sheets("Tracker").Range("C" & Last_Row + 1) = Full_Name
                Else
                    Sheets("Tracker").Range("C" & Last_Row + 1) = Full_Name
                    Sheets("Tracker").Range("C" & Last_Row + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
           End If
         End With
       End If
 Last_Row = Last_Row + 1
 Next R
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another test in case `i_Cell` was not set on this line:

```
Set i_Cell = .Find(What:="*" & Candi_ID, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Something like:

```
If Full_Name <> vbNullString And Not i_Cell Is Nothing Then
```

If it is `Nothing`, and you don't test for this further down, you will get the error you mention.

Also, you have a duplicate declaration, some missing declarations, and use `Long` rather than `Integer`. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of all your modules. Avoid `.Select`, which slows your code, and use `With` statements where possible.

I replaced the empty literal string `""` with `vbNullString`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply QHarr, I'll correct my code. One small follow up question if you don't mind, is it possible to use Offset in the way I intend to? As in, base it on the result of Find.

Comment: Something like: "If Full_Name = i_Cell.Offset(0, -1) Then" when Offset looks to the cell on the left of i_Cell for the equivalent of Full_Name

Comment: Nothing wrong with it as it turns out, I managed to make it work :) Thank you for your help!